# use a standard js class to create an instance in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, class

how can i use a standard js class in a vue js component? i don't need anything static, just some regular js class. if this is not possible, i don't mind moving to react on angular. are they better than vue.js when it comes to code reusability?

Test.js file:

```
class Test
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.a = 'test';
    }
    
    test()
    {
        console.log( "test : " + this.a );
    }
}
```

vue component:

```
<script>
    import Test from './Test.js'
    
    export default {
        
        name:"whatever"
        
        ,mounted()
        {
            var test = new Test();
            
            test.a = "its working";
            test.test();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

when i execute this in a web browser the console shows the following error:
"TypeError: a() is not a constructor".

how can i get this to work?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the class as `export default class`, then everything is working fine.